# Using str_replace to remove spaces for exec()

Tags: php

I'm running into an issue with the function `str_replace()` while trying to create a shell command in PHP. In shell, when I tab-finish a line that has spaces, it comes up like this:

```
tar cvfz destination/filename.zip source/Name\ Of\ The\+\ Folder
```

So to me, this says that in order to run this command via `exec()`, I need to replace any spaces I would have in a string in PHP. To remedy this problem, I'm using

```
$q = str_replace(' ', '\ ' , $q);
```

at the start of my string parse, in order to format the spaces into "\ " instead of " ". The issue I'm having is that for this particular folder, it's also removing the plus symbol as well, and it formats it like this:

```
tar cvfz destination/Name\ Of\ The\ \ \ Folder.tgz source/Name\ Of\ The\ \ \ Folder
```

How can I set this up so `str_replace()` doesn't remove the plus sign? From my limited tests so far, it isn't removing anything out of these: `-, %, @, !, (, *, ), ^, =`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using string functions for this is **very wrong** and likely to leave **security holes** wide open.

PHP has a function called [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) that does exactly what you need:

> `escapeshellarg()` adds single quotes around a string and quotes/escapes any existing single quotes allowing you to pass a string directly to a shell function and having it be treated as a single safe argument. This function should be used to escape individual arguments to shell functions coming from user input.